# CI\CD for Windows Web Application

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration

What is the best way to Implement CI\CD for windows web application?
My plan is to 
1. Build using MSBuild in Jenkins
2. Move the Code to AWS S3
3. Use AWS lambda functions to deploy

Code is .net web app and our dev and qa servers are in AWS.

Is this a good approach?

Answer (score 0):

You may run your instance with IAM roles to upload to S3 or enter your AWS credentials via a secret parameter plugin in Jenkins. You may also check for the AWS Lambda plugins of jenkins. and also if you are using bitbucket or github to pull the source from add awebhook to the bitbucket (for example), to trigger the jenkins job whenever a developer pushes new source code to a specific repo. I hope this helps.

Comment: I was more interested in knowing, is this the correct way or should I go with an approach of windows containers.